# Grails 3 redirect after login

Tags: authentication, redirect, grails, spring-security, saml

In Grails (version 3.1.9), I'm trying to find a way to redirect user to a different page after they have logged in than it is right now. I didn't work with this application before, but from what I've noticed, it's using SpringSecurity and SAML, which I have never been working with until now. Here's the auth.gsp code that contains the login form:

```
<form action="/login/authenticate" method="POST" id="loginForm" class="cssform"
                    autocomplete="off">
                    <label for="username"><g:message code='springSecurity.login.username.label'/>:</label>

                    <div class="pg-input">
                        <input type="text" name="${usernameParameter ?: 'username'}" id="username"/>
                    </div>

                    <label for="password"><g:message code='springSecurity.login.password.label'/>:</label>

                    <div class="pg-input">
                        <input type="password" name="${passwordParameter ?: 'password'}" id="password"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pg-row">
                        <button class="pg-button square" role="button" type="submit" id="submit"
                                value="${message(code: 'springSecurity.login.button')}"
                        >Log in</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I'm new to this, but if I'm correct, the `action="/login/authenticate"` refers to SpringSecurity.

Here are some parts of the Config.groovy class code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
// Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
    @Bean
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
                new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
        successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/content")
        successRedirectHandler.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true)
        return successRedirectHandler
    }

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingEntryPoint())
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint())
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable()
        http
                .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers('/admin/**').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/panel').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/index/**').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/admin/**').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/item/**').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/category/**').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/serviceUser/**').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/serviceRole/**').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/fileLink/**').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers('/serviceUserServiceRole/**').hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers("/error").hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
                    .antMatchers("/content").fullyAuthenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/content/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/assets/files/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
        http
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
    }
```

What I've tried so far:

- in `successRedirectHandler()` method, changing the `setDefaultTargetUrl("/content")` to `setDefaultTargetUrl("https://www.google.com")` and `setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true)` to `setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(false)`
- in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method adding `http.loginForm().defaultSuccessUrl("https://www.google.com", true)`

For now, after user logs in, application redirects from http://localhost:443/login/auth to http://localhost:443/content/index. I need to find where this path is specified, but I have no ideas anymore. I also think it may be related to the SAML, but I have no idea how to use it at this moment and learning it from scratches may take some time. Tell me if I should add more information as I'm not sure if what I've put here is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's incredible, how after hours of research I post a question and find the answer immediately after.

I've found that there's been a property specified in the application.yml - successHandler.defaultTargetUrl : '/content/index'

After changing it, the application works as I wanted. It seems that application.yml properties override everything that's specified in the other files.